# What does this hibernate criteria example do?

Tags: hibernate

I saw the following criteria example on [hibernate tutorial web site](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html), but I didn't know what it does, can somebody help explain?

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") )
.createCriteria("kittens")
    .add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") )
.list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns all the cats whose name starts with F and who have at least one child whose name starts with F.

It's equivalent to the following HQL:

```
select cat from Cat cat
join cat.kittens child
where cat.name like 'F%' and child like 'F%'
```

Comment: but the list() method was called on the second criteria created with "kittens", why it returns cat list as the first criteria?

Comment: Because the subcriteria's list method delegates to its parent list method.